# Verb for a tail "slipping" out of a piece of clothing?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is there any specific verb (or anything that sounds more natural than "slip") that could be used in the following sentence:

"Its tail slipped underneath its skirt."

Comment: *Peeped out* [from underneath its skirt]?

Comment: One wonders what sort of animal this is that wears skirts.

Comment: But are you looking for "mooned" or "plumber's butt"?

Comment: @HotLicks Check the avatar. It's an anime animal. OP is writing fanfic or something like it.

Comment: @DanBron Hey, shhh, don't expose me like that. But it's indeed an "anime" sort of character, well deducted.

Comment: @HotLicks Both implies that my character's "butt" is exposed, right? I'm just looking for a verb which can be used to describe the character's tail getting out of its clothes, without lifting its dress or exposing anything in the process (beyond the tail, of course).

Comment: @DanBron or "**peeked**"

Comment: Well, you could always use "plumber's tail", I suppose.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you're thinking about this the wrong way. It's not something so coarse as a blue collar buttcrack. Imagine seeing an elegant lady walking down the street, her airy skirts swishing with her delicate steps. At some moment, the orange tip of her long, tiger-like tail -- *which isn't supposed to be there* -- pokes out, momentarily, just momentarily, from under her skirt. She's secretly a chimera. Or, more classically, what verb would you to describe the momentary, thrilling, and somewhat scandalous a accidental exposure of a Victorian lady's ankle in public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Its tail slipped **from** beneath its skirt.  I've always heard "slip beneath" as a synonym for "hide," as in an animal slipping beneath a rock.

Now, some other options:

- peep out
- poke out
- sneak out
- slide out

You could also reword the sentence to the effect of something like "Its skirt shifted to reveal a tail." And of course, there's the option to replace 'shifted' with something that fits the scene: "Its skirt wafted in the breeze, revealing its tail."